# What is ||=[] in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

What does below array `@{$violated{$desc}||=[]}` mean in below subroutine?
I understand  `@{$violated{$desc}}` is the anonymous array referenced by `$violated{$desc}`, though.

```
sub not_in_file_ok {
    my ($filename, %regex) = @_;
    open( my $fh, '<', $filename ) or die "couldn't open $filename for reading: $!";
    my %violated;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        while (my ($desc, $regex) = each %regex) {
            if ($line =~ $regex) {
                push @{$violated{$desc}||=[]}, $.;
            }
        }
    }
    if (%violated) {
    fail("$filename contains boilerplate text");
    diag "$_ appears on lines @{$violated{$_}}" for keys %violated;
    } else {
    pass("$filename contains no boilerplate text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for `||=` in perlop, and `[]` returns array ref. If clarity is of any significance, it should be written as  `$violated{$desc} ||= []; push @{$violated{$desc}}, $.;`

Answer (score 9):

It's a [compound assignment operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators); it assigns `[]` (a reference to a new empty array) to `$violated{$desc}` if it contains a false value (i.e. if it hasn't been initialized yet).

It's also completely unnecessary, because Perl does that automatically anyway. The same code with `||=[]` removed does the same thing, more clearly.

However, there are times when it actually does make sense to do something like this, so it's worth keeping the pattern in mind.

Comment: The term is "autovivification" http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/

Answer (score 7):

`$x ||= []` is pretty much equivalent to `$x = $x || []`, which is, in turn, almost equivalent to `$x = $x ? $x : []`. In other words, if `$x` is falsy, it will make it an empty array reference; otherwise, it will leave it alone.

Answer (score 2):

Logical or with assignment. It takes left operand, and right operand, performs `left || right` and assigns it back to `left`.

Check [perl assignment operators](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/Operators#Assignment)